# How does jwt implement RSA256 signature verification in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, jwt, rsa, digital-signature

I was trying to understand the internal working of how JWT performs RS256 signature verification. The signature algorithm works on following basic steps:

1. Hash the original data
2. Encrypt the hash with RSA private key

And for verification it follows the following steps:

1. Decrypt using RSA public key
2. Match the hash generated from decryption with the SHA256 hash of original message.

While trying to test this on one of the jwt
`eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA`

I found that the **hash obtained from signature contains some extra characters**.
E.g. the SHA256 of original message in case of above jwt in hex encoding is

`8041fb8cba9e4f8cc1483790b05262841f27fdcb211bc039ddf8864374db5f53`

but the hash obtained from signature of above jwt after decryption is
`3031300d0609608648016503040201050004208041fb8cba9e4f8cc1483790b05262841f27fdcb211bc039ddf8864374db5f53`

Which has `3031300d060960864801650304020105000420` extra characters infront of the hash.

What do these characters represent and shouldn't the hash obtained from message and signature be identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rfc7518 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.3) defines JWS algorithms RS256,384,512:

```
   This section defines the use of the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 digital
   signature algorithm as defined in Section 8.2 of RFC 3447 [RFC3447]
   (commonly known as PKCS #1), using SHA-2 [SHS] hash functions.
```

and [rfc3447 8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-8.2) defines RSASS-PKCS1-v1_5

```
   RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 combines the RSASP1 and RSAVP1 primitives with the
   EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding method.   ....
```

where EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is defined in [rfc3447 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.2) as:

```
   1. Apply the hash function to the message M to produce a hash value
      H:

         H = Hash(M).

      If the hash function outputs "message too long," output "message
      too long" and stop.

   2. Encode the algorithm ID for the hash function and the hash value
      into an ASN.1 value of type DigestInfo (see Appendix A.2.4) with
      the Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER), where the type DigestInfo
      has the syntax

      DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
          digestAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
          digest OCTET STRING
      }

      The first field identifies the hash function and the second
      contains the hash value.  Let T be the DER encoding of the
      DigestInfo value (see the notes below) and let tLen be the length
      in octets of T.

   3. If emLen < tLen + 11, output "intended encoded message length too
      short" and stop.

   4. Generate an octet string PS consisting of emLen - tLen - 3 octets
      with hexadecimal value 0xff.  The length of PS will be at least 8
      octets.

   5. Concatenate PS, the DER encoding T, and other padding to form the
      encoded message EM as

         EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T.

   6. Output EM. [added: which is then modexp'ed with d by RSASP1 to
   sign, or matched to the value modexp'ed with e by RSAVP1 to verify]

   Notes.

   1. For the six hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER
      encoding T of the DigestInfo value is equal to the following:

      MD2:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 02 05 00 04
                   10 || H.
      MD5:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05 05 00 04
                   10 || H.
      SHA-1:   (0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 || H.
      SHA-256: (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00
                   04 20 || H.
      SHA-384: (0x)30 41 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02 05 00
                   04 30 || H.
      SHA-512: (0x)30 51 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03 05 00
                      04 40 || H.
```

The prefix you discovered corresponds exactly to that specified in Note 1 for the encoding in step 2 of a DigestInfo structure for a SHA-256 hash, as expected.

Note rfc3447=PKCS1v2.1 has been superseded by rfc8017=PKCS1v2.2, but the only relevant change in this area is the addition of the SHA512/224 and SHA512/256 hashes, which JWS doesn't use.

Describing signing and verifying as 'encrypting' and 'decrypting' the hash (really, the encoding aka padding of the hash) is considered obsolete. It was used originally, decades ago, and only for RSA not other signature algorithms, because of the mathematical similarity between the modexp operations used for encrypting and decrypting vs signing and verifying, but it was found that thinking of these as the same or interchangeable resulted in system implementations that were vulnerable and broken. In particular see [rfc3447 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-5.2):

```
   The main mathematical operation in each primitive is
   exponentiation, as in the encryption and decryption primitives of
   Section 5.1.  RSASP1 and RSAVP1 are the same as RSADP and RSAEP
   except for the names of their input and output arguments; they are
   distinguished as they are intended for different purposes.
```

nodejs uses this obsolete terminology because it uses OpenSSL which via its predecessor SSLeay dates back to the early 1990s when this mistake was still common.
However, that isn't really a programming/development issue and is more on topic for crypto.SX and security.SX; see some of the links I collected at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request#159289 .

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. This really helps.